# Acceptance checkbox working but not showing check mark

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I don't know why but the checkbox at the bottom on this contact form works ( enables the submit button ) but doesn't show the check mark when it's checked.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey there if you are removing the class `form-control` from the checkbox everything is working as expected.

Check the source code of your JavaScript files as well as your Stylesheets for class `form-control` and eliminate the problem.

Comment: Awesome!. Thank you!. I'd been banging my head the whole afternoon. With your advice I just have to grep the template files for that class and I found the culprit on one JavaScript that unchecked the checkbox after been checked.